# Loop through the JSON data inside Django template

Tags: arrays, json, django

I want to loop through this Json data in my Django Template. Although, I have achieve it but I have some similar array which I find difficult to loop through because of the Similarity in their name. Like I have two flightSegment.

[image]

```
[{'type': 'flight-offer', 'id': '1572710950059-668908355', 'offerItems': [{'services': [{'segments': [{'flightSegment': {'departure': {'iataCode': 'LOS', 'terminal': 'I', 'at': '2020-01-01T00:40:00+01:00'}, 'arrival': {'iataCode': 'JFK', 'terminal': '4', 'at': '2020-01-01T06:32:00-05:00'}, 'carrierCode': 'DL', 'number': '219', 'aircraft': {'code': '332'}, 'operating': {'carrierCode': 'DL', 'number': '219'}, 'duration': '0DT11H52M'}, 'pricingDetailPerAdult': {'travelClass': 'ECONOMY', 'fareClass': 'U', 'availability': 9, 'fareBasis': 'UL10J3M2'}}]}, {'segments': [{'flightSegment': {'departure': {'iataCode': 'LGA', 'terminal': 'D', 'at': '2020-02-02T19:00:00-05:00'}, 'arrival': {'iataCode': 'ATL', 'terminal': 'S', 'at': '2020-02-02T21:41:00-05:00'}, 'carrierCode': 'DL', 'number': '2778', 'aircraft': {'code': '321'}, 'operating': {'carrierCode': 'DL', 'number': '2778'}, 'duration': '0DT2H41M'}, 'pricingDetailPerAdult': {'travelClass': 'ECONOMY', 'fareClass': 'T', 'availability': 9, 'fareBasis': 'TL10J3M3'}}, {'flightSegment': {'departure': {'iataCode': 'ATL', 'terminal': 'I', 'at': '2020-02-02T22:25:00-05:00'}, 'arrival': {'iataCode': 'LOS', 'terminal': 'I', 'at': '2020-02-03T15:10:00+01:00'}, 'carrierCode': 'DL', 'number': '54', 'aircraft': {'code': '332'}, 'operating': {'carrierCode': 'DL', 'number': '54'}, 'duration': '0DT10H45M'}, 'pricingDetailPerAdult': {'travelClass': 'ECONOMY', 'fareClass': 'T', 'availability': 9, 'fareBasis': 'TL10J3M3'}}]}], 'price': {'total': '1415.86', 'totalTaxes': '623.86'}, 'pricePerAdult': {'total': '1415.86', 'totalTaxes': '623.86'}}]},
```

Comment: Did you go through my answer. try the approach and tell me the results

Answer (score 0):

```
json= {'segments': [{'flightSegment': {'departure': {'iataCode': 'JFK', 'terminal': '4', 'at': '2020-02-02T19:31:00-05:00'}, 'arrival': {'iataCode': 'AMS', 'at': '2020-02-03T09:10:00+01:00'}, 'carrierCode': 'KL', 'number': '6007', 'aircraft': {'code': '76W'}, 'operating': {'carrierCode': 'DL', 'number': '6007'}, 'duration': '0DT7H39M'}, 'pricingDetailPerAdult': {'travelClass': 'ECONOMY', 'fareClass': 'N', 'availability': 9, 'fareBasis': 'NLSRNG'}}, {'flightSegment': {'departure': {'iataCode': 'AMS', 'at': '2020-02-03T10:20:00+01:00'}, 'arrival': {'iataCode': 'CDG', 'terminal': '2F', 'at': '2020-02-03T11:45:00+01:00'}, 'carrierCode': 'KL', 'number': '2007', 'aircraft': {'code': '321'}, 'operating': {'carrierCode': 'AF', 'number': '2007'}, 'duration': '0DT1H25M'}, 'pricingDetailPerAdult': {'travelClass': 'ECONOMY', 'fareClass': 'L', 'availability': 9, 'fareBasis': 'NLSRNG'}}, {'flightSegment': {'departure': {'iataCode': 'CDG', 'terminal': '2E', 'at': '2020-02-03T13:15:00+01:00'}, 'arrival': {'iataCode': 'ABV', 'at': '2020-02-03T19:20:00+01:00'}, 'carrierCode': 'KL', 'number': '2054', 'aircraft': {'code': '332'}, 'operating': {'carrierCode': 'AF', 'number': '2054'}, 'duration': '0DT6H5M'}, 'pricingDetailPerAdult': {'travelClass': 'ECONOMY', 'fareClass': 'N', 'availability': 9, 'fareBasis': 'NLSRNG'}}]} 

for x in json.get("segments"):
  print(x.get("flightSegment").get("departure").get("iataCode"))
```

Comment: So, I will like to pull the Data into my Template in Django. Hope you understand it now

Comment: Clearly the OP wants to loop throught the json in the template.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your json data to the template. Lets suppose the name is data. In the views function pass the context as:

```
context['data'] = data
```

Pass this context to your template.
Now inside the template, iterate

```
{% for datum in data %}
    {{ datum.field}}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Access the dictionary inside the dictionary by chaining the dot operator.
Hope this helps.

Comment: The structure of the Data is the issue. I have done that in my template. but viewing the result accordingly is the issue

Comment: please clearly state that how do you want the output to be what fields do you want to access

Comment: I want to output the departure (iataCode, Terminal) arrival(iataCode, terminal)